# ¿Como crear Banners con Admob?

Tags: android, admob

Mi problema es que no me aparecen o muestra los banner en la pantalla, actualmente mi código que es de la pagina oficial de admob no funciona, la pagina es: [esta](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/games).

El código es este:

```
    private void crear(){
    SurfaceView gameView = new SurfaceView(this);

    // Create and load the AdView.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1765002374395487/9026293652");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    // Create a RelativeLayout as the main layout and add the gameView.
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainLayout.addView(gameView);

    // Add adView to the bottom of the screen.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    mainLayout.addView(adView, adParams);

    showBanner();
}

private void showBanner() {
      adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
    }
```

Este código es el mismo que da admob excepto que lo he modificado colocandolo dentro de un método.

Si saben donde fallo por favor decírmelo o conocen otra forma, estaré encantado de escuchar su idea. Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar toda la clase por favor? Tu adUnit esta activado?

Answer (score 3):

Debes contener los permisos dentro del AndroidManifest.xml , recuerda que debe permitir tu aplicación conexión a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Es importante revisar que el id del AdUnit corresponde a un anuncio activo, si lo anterior es correcto, puedo comentarte que tu implementación es correcta pero al parecer el problema es con el `SMART_BANNER` que no tiene espacio requerido para desplegarse,

> **SMART_BANNER**
>
> - orientación vertical requiere 411x50 dp
> - orientación horizontal requiere 683x50 dp

Prueba mostrando otra medida como `LARGE_BANNER` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante revises el **LogCat** donde mostrará que es necesario para el despliegue. No es necesario "vincular la aplicación que se encuentra en google play, con admob", precisamente en el **LogCat** puede sugerirte agregues un dispositivo de prueba para poder desplegar los anuncios:

> Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to
>   get test ads on this device.

ejemplo:

```
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345")
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
```

---

---

Mensajes comunes que nos indican que no se puede cargar el anuncio por tener un espacio inadecuado.

> - W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 411x50 dp, but only has
>     379x571 dp.
> - W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 683x50 dp, but
>     only has 651x307 dp.

Comment: Ya tengo esos permisos. Gracias

Comment: Lo mejor es revisar el LogCat ahí muestra el problema, incluso si tu UnitAd es incorrecta o necesitas configurar un dispositivo, podrías agregar toda la clase? .

Comment: Ya lo he verificado pero no me da o muestra ningún error. Y una pregunta he hecho una investigación en este tema y no se si es necesario tener vinculada la aplicación que se encuentra en google play, con admob para ver los anuncios, porque yo aun no he publicado mi app. Gracias

Comment: Un mensaje desplegado en el LogCat sobre el AdMob puede No desplegarse como error, puede ser un Warning : W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 411x50 dp, but only has 300x500 dp.