# ¿Cómo poner publicidad de adMob en mi app con android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Estoy poniendo publicidad a mi aplicación. He optado por el tipo `banner`.

Es mi primera vez, así que he seguido un tutorial que me encontré por la red y finalmente **he logrado que el "banner" cargue una publicidad de prueba** cuyo id: `ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"`.  Pero al reemplazar el **id** de prueba por el de mi bloque de anuncios, no me sale ningún error, ni aparece la publicidad en la app.

**¿Qué cambios más debo hacer para que aparezca la publicidad?**

Comment: bueno yo no soy un experto en Android pero hace tiempo hice una aplicacion gracias a esta informacion : 
[Google][1]


[Tutorial paso paso de como hacer una aplicacion con anuncios][2]


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial
  [2]: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/adding-google-admob-ads-android-appbanner-interstitial-ads/

Comment: He revisado el contenido de esos enlaces. Pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. He encontrado un tutorial donde dicen que **los anuncios de adMob no funcionan si no tenemos publicada la aplicación en la Play-Store**

Comment: @Tony_Bielo no es asi, tengo aplicaciones no publicadas que contienen adMob, los anuncios son mostrados y he recibido pagos.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Comment: @Jose D. Jurado, la app en cuestión se ha creado en `android-studio`. El problema podría ser por una mala implementación en el entorno de desarrollo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo pongo como respuesta ya que seguramente sea lo que te está ocurriendo, ademas agregare un ejemplo.
Cuando creas una app y le colocas adMob, dese hace unas actualizaciones atrás, solamente la publicidad seria visible en dispositivos reales, y no en el emulador propio de Android Studio. Ademas de esto, a la hora de cargar la publicidad en tu código, puedes especificar `id` de prueba para que la publicidad no sea visible en dicho terminal.
Esto se debe a que no se pueden hacer click en los anuncios propios, siendo penalizado por Google adMob.
Así que para ver si realmente la publicidad esta siendo mostrada, instala la aplicacion en un dispositivo real.

Código para colocar los anuncios tipo banner:

En tu layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

En tu archivo de manifiesto:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Por ultimo en tu actividad:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Edito:

Si en tu aplicacion tienes tanto un id de prueba `adRequest.addTestDevice("ID")`, como si estas usando un emulador, lo que verias seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya tengo hecho todo eso.  He estado probando la app en un dispositivo real, en el que tengo mi cuenta google!!!  **¿Es posible que sea el problema?**.  No tengo otro dispositivo para verificarlo.

Comment: No creo eso no es problema, en mis dispositivos tengo la cuenta y estos son mostrados. En la parte donde cargas el anuncio, tienes algo como esto ? `adRequest.addTestDevice("");` si es asi, es por causa de eso, unicamente deberias eliminar dicha linea.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, agregando una imagen de lo que deberias ver en caso de todo estar bien pero usando o un emulador o un id de prueba. Si no ves eso, entonces podrias indicar que es lo que visualizas?

Comment: **EXACTAMENTE!!!** Esa es la imagen que me sale al usar un ID de prueba o un emulador.  Pero quiero saber qué falta para que se vean los anuncios en los dispositivos que instalen mi app!!! en vez de esa imagen.  REPITO: al cambiear el ID de prueba **A** por el de mi bloque **B**, ya no me aparece nada.

Comment: Tras cambiar el id, los anuncios serán mostrados sin hacer nada mas, lo único que podría decirte es que revises que el ID del anuncio que estas colocando sea del tipo baner y no interstitial, por si sin darte cuenta estas colocando uno que no corresponde.

Comment: Jejejej... Ya está hecho. Mientras comprobaba el ID anuncio, se me apareció un mensaje en mi cuenta que decía: "Los anuncios no se mostrarán en tu aplicación hasta que registres los datos de pago". Entonces registé mis datos. (Haberme mostrado el mensaje mucho antes, digo yo!)  xD

Answer (score 0):

> Pero al reemplazar el id de prueba por el de mi bloque de anuncios, no
>   me sale ningún error, ni aparece la publicidad en la app.

Revisa que el `adUnitId` sea valido para tu paquete de aplicación.

---

Es importante revises el LogCat ahí se mostraría el posible problema que puede ser:

- Tu aplicación no tiene permisos para conexión a internet. Asegura agregar el permiso

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

dentro de tu AndroidManifest.

- El adUnitId no es valido, asegura que el anuncio este activo 
  .
- El espacio para mostrar el anuncio no es suficiente. Por ejemplo:

> W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 683x50 dp, but only has
>   651x307 dp.

- Necesitas definir el id de un dispositivo de prueba.

> Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test
>   ads on this device.

- Asegura definir correctamente el tamaño deseado, en este caso:

> `ads:adSize="BANNER"`

Si aseguras lo anterior puedes desplegar tu anuncio sin problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta pregunta similar:

[¿Como crear Banners con Admob?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56094/como-crear-banners-con-admob/56109#56109)

Comment: Pensaba que si ya puedo ver anuncios de pruba de admob, es porque tengo bien los permisos, el adSize, etc. En el logCat me sale:    

`I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring`
**En rojo**
`E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)`