# Al poner publicidad (Admob) en mi app con mi Id de bloque de anuncio este no se muestra

Tags: android-studio, admob

He seguido al pie de la letra el tutorial de google para colocar publicidad tipo banner, incluyendo colocar el .addTestDevice. Cuando uso el id de prueba de google en el xml el banner de publicidad se muestra bien, pero cuando uso mi id de banner este no se muestra en mi dispositivo ni en el emulador. 
Seguí también las indicaciones de una pregunta similar
[¿Cómo poner publicidad de adMob en mi app con android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83204/c%C3%B3mo-poner-publicidad-de-admob-en-mi-app-con-android-studio)
pero tampoco funciona.

Encontré en Run lo siguiente:

```
E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.
```

Estos son mis codigos usados para ello:
XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
```

java

```
  MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.ADMOB_APP_ID));
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3B9095AF182DC10132E1E9AF48C95919").build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/ADMOB_APP_ID"
            />
```

dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cuando uso el id de prueba de google en el xml el banner de publicidad
>   se muestra bien, pero cuando uso mi id de banner este no se muestra en
>   mi dispositivo ni en el emulador.

En realidad no creo que exista problema, ya que si no estas usando el id del dispositivo de prueba:

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3B9095AF182DC10132E1E9AF48C95919").build();
```

el mensaje indica que la inicialización de Google Mobile Ads SDK no está disponible para esta sesión, lo que debes realizar para que se muestren los anuncios es firmar tu .apk para Play store y los anuncios deben mostrarse sin problema.